# Blank screen when navigating, Xamarin Forms IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

We ran into strange bug on IOS. When using a master navigation page when we 'pop to root' we get stuck at a blank page. By blank page I mean there is no content (just white).

The page that causes this includes a customer full screen video render. 
Could that be the cause ? If not, what could be the cause.

Our current work around is to replace the master navigation page completely. (App.MainPage = new...). This works, but causes a noticeable reload of our content which is less than satisfactory.

Comment: Check Navigation.NavigationStack before using Navigation.PopToRootAsync and check if the first page is the expected one. Also, do you use Navigation.PopToRootAsync on other pages and it works?

Comment: What is in the video render page's constructor and `OnAppearing()`? Could it be that since only `OnAppearing()` is being called when you 'pop to root' something is not being completely/properly initialized? Also do you see any errors in `Output` after popping?

Comment: @Gusman Hi, I work with San. Checking the navigation stack, shows a stack of three pages (correct). @hvaghan3 , I don`t follow. This call is happening well after init (from a button click in some cases).

I should add we feel this is related to a custom renderer. I see old bug reports with similar issues on bugzilla.